# How to avoid becoming an unofficial full-time employee

Tags: job-offer, negotiation, freelancing, consulting

Shared on Freelancing: https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/8149/11018

---

I've been proposed a freelance job, but it's basically a full-time job but with no benefits.

- 40-hours, M-F
- Work in their office
- Work with their equipment
- Follow their directions; they direct the work, not me
- Working on multiple projects; whatever they choose

They are asking for an hourly rate, but I am not sure how to propose a fair number or work agreement.

My last gig was very similar to this, but almost worse, and in the end they cut me when the direction I received and implemented wasn't to the liking of their client.

Comment: Unless there's a reason, cross posting is usually frowned upon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cross-posting on SE is generally [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). While I could see it being (potentially) on topic here see how it plays out on Freelancing first

Comment: Freelancing says it's in Beta, whereas this forum is not. There are already responses on this question.

Comment: I for one am interested in the answer.

Comment: Is this in the US?  Sounds like you could make a case for co-employment

Comment: Is this the US? The IRS takes a dim view of employers who try to treat employees as contractors.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Yes, the US. Honestly, this isn't the first company I've known to do this. The last place I worked, I realized this was the case. And, in fact, in their "contract" they wouldn't even let me quit unless *they* gave notice. I have been advised that turning them in to the IRS would clearly be a burning the bridges move.

Comment: @acpilot If it's not filing some paperwork with the IRS, then I'm not sure what "co-employment" means.

Comment: It is also called joint employment.  It's a common trap that companies fall for when they think they're being clever by using contractors in FTE roles.  Sony and Microsoft have been dinged for this as have many other smaller companies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to avoid it?  Declining their offer is the simplest way.

But if you really would like to work for this company, then negotiate an hourly rate that you would expect to get doing regular freelance work and would make up for the fact that they are providing no benefits.  If they don't accept, then simply move on to another opportunity.

Comment: From a business-perspective I would calculate the hourly rate significantly higher than a regular employee would receive including benefits. The company has the added benefit of flexibility with freelance workes, while you carry the downside of flexibility e.g. you can be cut at any given time. Your hourly rate should reflect a compensation for this insecurity compared to a regular employee.

Comment: @MrTony Yes. In a recent question, I asked about using a formula to determine a day rate, and then using the day rate to calculate the hourly rate. In either case, both the day rate and the hourly rate are higher than a straight transfer from a regular employee salary due to the premium added for lack of benefits. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/131342/advice-when-pitching-a-day-rate-to-maximize-billable-time